# Getting URL from javascript webpage

Tags: javascript, bash, url, wget

I need to semi-automatize getting links from page by wget and bash line editors. The source code does not contain these URL's. Is it possible to get URL's this way or with a similar one?

The webpage is for example `http://uloz.to/hledej?protected=notPassword&redir=0&q=picture&media=image` and I want to get direct URL's to those found items (in this case 52).

I noticed that in a web browser running in Windows I am not able to open it in next tab, but on Linux I am. Is there any connection?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish, and what you have tried so far (including code)?

Comment: use search for some keyword at this website and get links to its result. Ive tried wget *URL above*, but it doesnt contain it

Comment: I still don't understand clearly what you are trying to do, and some code would be great.

Comment: if you click on the first search result, you will be redirect to: http://uloz.to/xxS5hZPD/futurama-wallpapers-anime-picture-futurama-wallpapers-jpg .This is the URL adress I want to get without clicking. I want to get it for every search result that appears on the page. I dont use any code, I am just wondering if it is possible